# Did the Buddha ever cure someone?

Tags: the-buddha, death

Perhaps you could say that by teaching his path he healed many people; but what I meant is more direct, physical healing: is there something written about that?

Comment: What is physical healing and to which extend does healing count as healing in regard of this question. Actually no body ever got healed by anyone, they all broke apart, sooner or later. And if thinking about this, whom did he not healed when having taking his medicine?

Answer (score 3):

This article [Ministering to the Sick and the Terminally Ill](http://www.urbandharma.org/udharma3/sick.html) contains examples (references to suttas and the vinaya), certainly of caring for or ministering to people who are physically unwell.

There are also some accounts of people being "healed": see for example the paragraphs which begin,

> It seems that those who are highly developed mentally are able to suppress illness ...

See also the paragraph which begins,

> The advice given by Nakulamata to Nakulapita ...

Answer (score 1):

As per a legend, Vaishali was once infested with plague and with Buddha's arrival, the plague ended. so there are many stories by later additions that Buddha was the direct cause for eradicating the plague.  Some stories originating from SE Asia, one suggests that Buddha gave his Alms bowl to ven. Ananda to make holy water to sprinkle around town.  This was probably untrue, given that in at least 13 sutta, Buddhda prohibits monks to make holy water.  This one strange sutta doesnt fit in.  Some scholars and experts believe that this story is the reason why you see today's monks sprinkle holy water in temples, especially in south east Asia countries.